# sheets of Excel Workbook from a URL into a `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: python, url, pandas, xlrd

After looking at different ways to read an url link, pointing to a .xls file, I decided to go with using xlrd.

I am having a difficult time converting a 'xlrd.book.Book' type to a 'pandas.DataFrame'

I have the following:

```
import pandas
import xlrd 
import urllib2

link ='http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/chapt26.xls'
socket = urllib2.urlopen(link)

#this line gets me the excel workbook 
xlfile = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents = socket.read())

#storing the sheets
sheets = xlfile.sheets()
```

I want to tak the last sheet of `sheets` and import as a `pandas.DataFrame`, any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?  I've tried, `pandas.ExcelFile.parse()` but it wants a path to an excel file.  I can of certainly save the file to memory and then parse (using `tempfile` or something), but I'm trying to follow pythonic guidelines and use functionality *likely* already written into pandas.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass your `socket` to `ExcelFile`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import urllib2
>>> link = 'http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/chapt26.xls'
>>> socket = urllib2.urlopen(link)
>>> xd = pd.ExcelFile(socket)
NOTE *** Ignoring non-worksheet data named u'PDVPlot' (type 0x02 = Chart)
NOTE *** Ignoring non-worksheet data named u'ConsumptionPlot' (type 0x02 = Chart)
>>> xd.sheet_names
[u'Data', u'Consumption', u'Calculations']
>>> df = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-1], header=None)
>>> df
                                   0   1   2   3         4
0        Average Real Interest Rate: NaN NaN NaN  1.028826
1    Geometric Average Stock Return: NaN NaN NaN  0.065533
2              exp(geo. Avg. return) NaN NaN NaN  0.067728
3  Geometric Average Dividend Growth NaN NaN NaN  0.012025
```

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a URL to `pandas.read_excel()`:

```
import pandas as pd

link ='http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/chapt26.xls'
data = pd.read_excel(link,'sheetname')
```