# How to download an xlsx file from a website to save as a dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I download a file:

[COVID-19 Data](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2fpeoplepopulationandcommunity%2fbirthsdeathsandmarriages%2fdeaths%2fdatasets%2fweeklyprovisionalfiguresondeathsregisteredinenglandandwales%2f2020/referencetablescorrected.xlsx) to be able to save one of its sheets named `Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences` as a dataframe.

The url works if I put it in a browser.

I have tried:

```
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd    

url = 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2fpeoplepopulationandcommunity%2fbirthsdeathsandmarriages%2fdeaths%2fdatasets%2fweeklyprovisionalfiguresondeathsregisteredinenglandandwales%2f2020/referencetablescorrected.xlsx'

s=requests.get(url).content
df_deathsAges = pd.read_excel(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')), 
                          nrows = 25, header = 5, sheet_name='Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences')
```

but I get the error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 15: invalid start byte`

I have tried:

```
url = 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2fpeoplepopulationandcommunity%2fbirthsdeathsandmarriages%2fdeaths%2fdatasets%2fweeklyprovisionalfiguresondeathsregisteredinenglandandwales%2f2020/referencetablescorrected.xlsx'

df_deathsAges = pd.read_excel(url,'Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences')
```

But I get the error:

`HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

What is the best way to proceed to accomplish this task?

Comment: xslx is a binary format, try `io.BytesIO(s)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sheets of Excel Workbook from a URL into a \`pandas.DataFrame\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588713/sheets-of-excel-workbook-from-a-url-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @AnthonySottile that worked, thank you

Comment: @lopezdp i tried all that but failed to make it work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xlsx` is a binary format and it's not valid UTF-8. Try to load it into pandas as a binary file stream:

```py
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd    

url = 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2fpeoplepopulationandcommunity%2fbirthsdeathsandmarriages%2fdeaths%2fdatasets%2fweeklyprovisionalfiguresondeathsregisteredinenglandandwales%2f2020/referencetablescorrected.xlsx'

s=requests.get(url).content
df_deathsAges = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(s),
                          nrows = 25, header = 5, sheet_name='Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences', engine="openpyxl")
```

Note: I tested the code and was not able to read the `xlsx` file with the default engine `xlrd`, but was successful with `openpyxl`

Comment: yes, very much seems i should have been using io.BytesIO(s)

Answer (score 4):

use `pd.ExcelFile` to parse multi-sheet xlsx files.

```
url = 'https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=%2fpeoplepopulationandcommunity%2fbirthsdeathsandmarriages%2fdeaths%2fdatasets%2fweeklyprovisionalfiguresondeathsregisteredinenglandandwales%2f2020/referencetablescorrected.xlsx'
s = requests.get(url).content

xl = pd.ExcelFile(s)  # io.BytesIO(s) is also work
xl.sheet_names        # see all sheet names
# xl.parse(sheet_name)  # read a specific sheet to DataFrame

['Analysis',
 'Contents',
 'Information',
 'Terms and conditions',
 'Weekly figures 2020',
 'Covid-19 - Weekly registrations',
 'Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences',
 'UK - Covid-19 - Weekly reg',
 'Covid-19 - Daily registrations',
 'Covid-19 - Daily occurrences',
 'Covid-19 - Place of occurrence ',
 'Estimated total deaths 2020',
 'Related publications']

df_deathsAges = xl.parse('Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences', nrows = 25, header = 5) 
df_deathsAges = df_deathsAges.dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

pd.read_excel can take bytes as input directly. This works for me:

```
df_deathsAges = pd.read_excel(s, 
                          nrows = 25, header = 5, sheet_name='Covid-19 - Weekly occurrences')
```